# How can I select a row with max frequency from a joint table?

Tags: mysql

Particularly, the tables are: articles, authors, authors_articles (connecting authors and articles), subjectareas (subject areas of the authors), and, authors_subjectareas (connecting authors to their subject areas).

I want to read from the article table row by row and find the authors of each article and then go to their subject areas and count the subject areas of all the co-authors of that article and finally assign the subject area with the maximum frequency to that article. I write a code as follows but the problem is it is doing it for all the articles not for each article separately!

```
select art.name as title, art.theAbstract as abstract, sub.name as subjectArea
from
articles as art, authors as aut, subjectareas as sub, authors_articles as aa, 
authors_subjectareas as asub 
where
art.id = aa.article and aut.id = aa.author and asub.author = aut.id and
sub.id = asub.subjectArea and (art.year >= 2000 and art.year <= 2004)
group by subjectArea
Order by count(subjectArea) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Would highly appreciate your comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeking to obtain the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) from a materialised table:

```
SELECT t2.name AS title, t2.theAbstract AS abstract, sub.name AS subjectArea
FROM (

  -- get each article's maximum co-author subject frequency
  SELECT art.id, MAX(freq) freq FROM (

    -- the subject frequencies of each article
    SELECT   art.id, COUNT(*) freq
    FROM     authors_articles aa
        JOIN authors_subjectareas asub USING (author)
        JOIN articles art ON art.id = aa.article
    GROUP BY art.id, asub.subjectArea

  ) t

) t1 NATURAL JOIN (

  -- the information we actually want
  SELECT   art.id, art.name, art.theAbstract, asub.subjectArea, COUNT(*) freq
  FROM     authors_articles aa
      JOIN authors_subjectareas asub USING (author)
      JOIN articles art ON art.id = aa.article
  GROUP BY art.id, asub.subjectArea

) t2 JOIN subjectareas sub ON sub.id = t2.subjectArea
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. Is there any way to make this kind of queries faster? The database is huge and the query takes to much time to run!